# Javascript InnerHTML display for two seconds

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

Okay so I've looked over previous similar questions and I'm not quite getting the answer. I have the below function that will display nicely but I want the display to end after two seconds. The second function was a a little experiment but delays the response for two seconds rather than displaying for two seconds. Any help would be great.

```
var j = 0;
function buttonClick() {
    text = ++j + " added to cart"
    document.getElementById('rope111').innerHTML = text;
}



var j = 0;
function buttonClick() {
    text = ++j + " added to cart"
    setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('rope111').innerHTML = text}, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var j = 0;
function buttonClick() {
    text = ++j + " added to cart";
    // First, we display the text with the statement below.
    document.getElementById('rope111').innerHTML = text;
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Then we remove the text after 2 seconds.
        document.getElementById('rope111').innerHTML = "";
    }, 2000);
}
```

You can also replace the statement in setTimeout function with:

```
document.getElementById('rope111').style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. As you found that

> ```
> var j = 0;
> function buttonClick() {
>     text = ++j + " added to cart";
>     document.getElementById('rope111').innerHTML = text;
> }
> ```

does what you want at the beginning (`text` appears, immediately), instead of reorganizing it randomly, you should just leave it in place nad add the new functionality to its end, without breaking what you already have:

```
var j = 0;
function buttonClick() {
    text = ++j + " added to cart";
    document.getElementById('rope111').innerHTML = text;

    setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('rope111').innerHTML = ""}, 2000);
}
```

(as you want `text` to disappear, you'll need an empty string `""`, but otherwise the new line comes from your snippets too)

Comment: I think three of you answered at the same time. All correct. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const emptyString = ""
const timeShown = 2000 // 2s
const addedToCartText = "added to cart"
let j = 0;

function buttonClick() {
  document.getElementById('rope111').innerHTML = `${++j} ${addedToCartText}`;
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById('rope111').innerHTML = emptyString
  }, timeShown)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="buttonClick()">Button</button>
<div id="rope111" />
```